# Trying to read the contents of a device pipe into a buffer causes errors

Tags: c, unix, pipe

My C/C++ program takes a file from the command line as an argument. Reading data from 'regular files' is no problem/general programming task, but when the file comes from a 'device pipe' such as /dev/fd/63 it causes my program to crash.

To reproduce:

from your friendly neighborhood bash shell supply a 'device pipe' as a file to your application. Your app should try to read the file contents into a buffer.

./yourapp <(echo 'Hello World!'); # /dev/fd/xx containing output from echo command.

**Note** the above command is not redirecting the standard input of the application and that is not the intended result..

I don't think that a lot of people know this will crash their application. The application 'seed' from the Gnome project uses glib to do its I/O but it can read from these files just fine. The command 'cat' can also handle this situation gracefully. Why is it when I try to read the contents of that named pipe like a regular file my application gets the crash bug?

EDIT: relavent code section

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *file;

    char *buffer;

    unsigned long fileLen;

    //Open file
    file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!file) return -1;

    //Get file length
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(file);

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //Allocate memory
    buffer=(char *)malloc(fileLen+1);

    if (!buffer){
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
        fclose(file);
        return -2;
    }

    //Read file contents into buffer
    fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    fprintf(stdout, "Size: %i", fileLen);

    free(buffer);

}
```

Comment: I think something is probably wrong.

Comment: _What_ error or crash do you get? Have you tried running the program in a debugger to see where the error is?

Comment: as the code demonstrates, the problem is that fileLen is -1! the code doesn't check that, and my program later went on to do things with that "buffer" which produced a seg fault. Sorry. I'm not a good c programmer yet so this wasn't really apparent to me. There is no such thing as a stupid question, only stupid answers!

Comment: Considering that you can potentially get more data from a pipe than you could fit in memory at one time you should reconsider your approach of trying to read the entire "file" into memory at once.

Comment: @evilotto makes sense to me. But I didn't write the original code. And the original code obviously didn't think about reading from a named pipe. So I was right that many programs aren't prepared for this situation.

Comment: @evilotto I'd like to express my grattitude for you pointing out that the input may never end. My application, will likely be recieving control script over the fifo. Well, these scripts need compiled before execution, so I have discovered that what I need is a recursive descent parser for the block statements and expressions.

Comment: adherance to this rule will allow the application to be controlled by other applications on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't call fseek on a pipe. The code shows that I was indeed trying to do such a foolish thing.